# How to add 6 hours on MSSQL with format

Tags: sql-server, format

I am currently using

> `SELECT FORMAT (getdate(), 'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt') as date`

The output is in the format I need, but is off by 6 hours.

> 05/30/2019, 06:26:01 PM

I just need to add 6 hours to it. been using dateadd, but I keep loosing the format I need it to be on.

> `SELECT DATEADD(Hours,6,GETDATE())` outputs in wrong format

Comment: So, why don't you combine the two?: `SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(Hours,6,GETDATE()), 'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt') AS date ;`

Comment: Or change the server to the desired timezone...

Comment: Thanks, I figured that is what I needed to do. just cant do it right, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the DATEADD function inside the FORMAT function:

```
SELECT FORMAT( DATEADD(HOUR, 6, GETDATE()), 'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt') as date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @dt datetime ;
select @dt=  DATEADD(Hour,6,GETDATE())
SELECT FORMAT (@dt, 'MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt') as date
```